# localStorage empty after refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I need to use `localStorage` in `nextjs` but after refresh i lose all the data (empty array [] in the console).
this is what i tried:

```
 const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || [];
    setTodos(storedTodos);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
```

This works in `React`:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(
    () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []
  );
```

but in `nextjs` i see `localstorage is not defined`.

**Thank you!**

Comment: Is there any error logged on the browser's console?

Comment: @Ahsan-J no nothing on the browser's console

Comment: @TrudMawn Try this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19911

Comment: @AhmadRaza365 i've seen it but i'm not sure how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `useEffect` was resetting the `localStorage` every refresh, so i added `todos.length === 0` to check:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if ((localStorage.getItem('todos')) === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify([])); // initialize here to prevent the null pointer in useeffect (todos.length)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    setTodos(storedTodos);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (todos.length === 0) {
      console.log("Array is empty!")
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
    }
  }, [todos]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just `localStorage.setItem('todos', "test");` without useEffect and check your whether your browser has saved it in local storage.

Please also make sure you're setting it in a class/function component.

[localstorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlXQc.png)

Comment: i see 'localstorage is not defined'